# Filemaker XML parser

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, filemaker

[Example returned XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukAOy.png)

When i convert the data from Filemaker to XML and if i want to import it in Woocommerce with the plugin All Importer the xml doesnt have valid fields, how can i match the field name's to the data fields? I tried to use simplexml to read the file and change the field names but with no success.
When i run this script i get only one result, i tried to dump the $this->data->RESULTSET there i get all the data in the XML but when i try to loop the $this->data->RESULTSET->ROW it look's like ROW is empty.

My code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!ini_get('display_errors'))
{
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

class Converter

{

    public function array2xml($array, $node_name = "xml")
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $root = $dom->createElement($node_name);
        $dom->appendChild($root);
        $array2xml =
            function ($node, $array) use($dom, &$array2xml)
            {
                foreach($array as $key => $value)
                {
                    if (is_array($value))
                    {
                        $n = $dom->createElement($key);
                        $node->appendChild($n);
                        $array2xml($n, $value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $attr = $dom->createAttribute($key);
                        $attr->value = htmlspecialchars($value);
                        $node->appendChild($attr);
                    }
                }
            };
        $array2xml($root, $array);
        return $dom->saveXML();
    }

    public function clean_explode($seperator, $string)
    {
        $result = trim($string, ' ' . $seperator);
        $result = explode($seperator, $result);
        $result = array_filter($result, 'strlen'); // removes double seperators
        $result = array_map('trim', $result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function sanitizer($text)
    {
        $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
        $text = trim($text, '-');
        $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);
        $text = strtolower($text);
        if (empty($text))
        {
            return 'n-a';
        }

        return $text;
    }

    public function import($file)
    {
        $this->data = simplexml_load_file($file);
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        foreach($this->data->RESULTSET as $xml_products)
        {
            foreach($xml_products->ROW as $xml_product){
            $product = new STDClass();
            $product->sku = (string)$xml_product->COL[0]->DATA;
            $product->brand = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode(':', (string)$xml_product->COL[1]->DATA));
            $product->name = (string)$xml_product->COL[2]->DATA;
            $product->description = (string)$xml_product->COL[3]->DATA;
            $product->price = str_replace(array(
                '.',
                ','
            ) , array(
                '',
                '.'
            ) , (string)$xml_product->COL[4]->DATA);
            $product->weight = (string)$xml_product->COL[5]->DATA;
            $sizes_a = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode(':', (string)$xml_product->COL[6]->DATA));
            $sizes_b = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode(':', (string)$xml_product->COL[7]->DATA));
            $product->sizes = array_unique(array_merge($sizes_a, $sizes_b));
            $colors_a = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode("\n", (string)$xml_product->COL[8]->DATA));
            $colors_b = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode("\n", (string)$xml_product->COL[9]->DATA));
            $product->colors = array_unique(array_merge($colors_a, $colors_b));
            $product->tags = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode(',', (string)$xml_product->COL[10]->DATA));
            $product->categories = array();
            for ($i = 11; $i < $xml_product->count(); $i++)
            {
                $categories = array_map([$this, 'sanitizer'], $this->clean_explode(',', (string)$xml_product->COL[$i]->DATA));
                $product->categories = array_unique(array_merge($product->categories, $categories));
            }

            if (isset($this->products[$product->name]))
            {
                $existing_product = $this->products[$product->name];
                $existing_product->categories = array_unique(array_merge($existing_product->categories, $product->categories));
                $this->products[$product->name] = $existing_product;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->products[$product->name] = $product;
            }
                return $product;

            }

        }

    }



    public function export()
    {
        $xml_product_ids = array();
        if (count($this->products) > 0)
        {
            foreach($this->products as $xml_product)
            {
                $xml_product_ids[] = $xml_product->sku;
                $product = !empty($products) ? $products[0] : null;
                $update = $product != null;
                if (!$update)
                {
                    $product = array(
                        'post_title' => $xml_product->name,
                        'post_name' => $xml_product->name,
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_excerpt' => '',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'post_author' => 1,
                        'post_type' => 'product'
                    );
                    return $this->array2xml($product);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$test = new Converter();
$dump = $test->import('../data/karoshi.xml');
$test->prepare();
print_r($test->export());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this out there real quick, I haven't had time to look over your code, so bear with me.
In the FMPXMLRESULT grammar the field names are in the METADATA/FIELD elements.
The data itself is in the RESULTSET/ROW/COL element, as you know.
The position of the FIELD in the METADATA element corresponds to the position of the COL in the ROW element.
You need to set up an array with the FIELD/@NAME to match the COL/DATA. Use the position as key. The you can access the COL elements by name.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for your comment, i already fixed it, ill publish soon a plugin for WordPress where you can import the Filemaker xml to convert it to valid XML

Comment: Cool, you doing this completely in PHP and not using any XSL transformation? I usually write an XSLT stylesheet any time I need the output from Filemaker to fit a certain format.

Comment: Yes completly in PHP, first you upload the exported XML file from FileMaker , after that it reads the XML file and rewrite the variables in a array, then i encode the array to json and from json to XML

Comment: http://recordit.co/OLIfxf59dm , the plugin is done here a quick preview @AndreasT